# Most efficient setup for sorted table with unique non-composite keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have a table where each item should have a unique non-composite key "id", some data and a "date" property. When reading this table I always want to return items ordered by "date". What is the best approach for this simple scenario?

**1**. Use ("id", "date") as the item primary key. 
   * Pro: don't need any secondary index. 
   * Con: "id" are not guaranteed to be unique

**2**. Use "id" alone as the primary key and create a secondary index on ("id", "date")
   * Pro: "id" is guaranteed to be unique
   * Con: An additional index is needed.

Also, if using approach 2 and never reading directly from the table, could I provision zero read capacity units for the table?

Answer (score 0):

There are some confusing statements in your question.

You claim that "id" is unique but the combination("id","date") is not. How can that be?

Then, in the first part say that you want to "read the table" (*do you mean return all the items in the table?!*) in sorted order by date. Then at the end you ask whether you could provision 0 read units to the table if you won't be reading from it. The answer is you can't provision 0 but you can provision 1 which is negligible $-wise

If you really do need to be able to order *all* items in the table by date than you have to options:

1. You can create a GSI with a partition key that encompases all items and use "date" as the range key but in this case you really need to question the use of DynamoDB
2. You can read the whole table in memory and order there
3. You can set up a hierarchical structure to have some coarse date component as the partition key and the full "date" as the sort key and compose results by potentially executing multiple queries to retrieve data